# Kubuntu 14.04 - No Screen resolution changer?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I just installed a fresh new kubuntu 14.04 on an intel nuc and everything works fine, but I can't find an option to change the screen resolution.

When I go to Settings -> Display I get the following weird screen:

[image: No screen resolution]

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: I have only one resolution available - 640x480

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer is right in front of your eyes!

[image]

Comment: Shame on me. :D

Comment: Shame on the UI.

Comment: wow.. that is micro and super obvious..

Comment: I have only the 1280x1024 option by my 1920x1080 monitor. (I use Mint, but I'll try with other distros soon. I think this really sux.)